# How to integrate Spring Security for Role based url/method access

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-4

I need to provide role based access for my REST APIs and I have seen that we could use `@PreAuthorize, @Secured` for this. However I am not sure as to what changes should I make and get this in place as currently I use a `custom token based authentication mechanism` generate a token for a session and handle it myself.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody Result login(@RequestBody Credentials credentials) {
        return loginService.login(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
        }
```

The Result class just contains a generated token for the user which he will be passing on each request.

Now any idea what changes should I make to restrict the access of an API if the user is in particular role

For example if I want to restrict the API `findById` to be accessed by user only if he is part of `ADMIN_ROLE` then I will have to add the `PreAuthorize` annotation but am not sure how will this determine the user role and block the user automatically.

```
@PreAuthorize("ADMIN_ROLE")
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Group findById(@PathVariable int id) {
    return groupParser.getGroupById(id, groupService.getGroupTree());
}
```

Comment: I handle a custom token based authentication 

@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public @ResponseBody Result login(@RequestBody Credentials credentials) {
        return loginService.login(credentials.getUsername(),credentials.getPassword());
   }

Comment: please, instead of explaining the configuration, post it :-) You'll have much more precise answer if you d so.

Comment: Thanks @StefanoCazzola . I have made some changes and have added some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to tweak Spring Security configuration. Below an example with XML config (I'm much more used to it); however, it is doable also in JavaConfig.

Basically, Spring security is fired by the

```
<http ....>
...
</http>
```

element. You'll need to write it like that (or something like that)

```
<beans:bean id="authenticatedVoter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
        <beans:property name="expressionHandler" ref="..." />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="roleVoter"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
        <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" /> <!-- if you want to customize role prefix -->
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:list>
                        <beans:ref bean="roleVoter" />
                        <beans:ref bean="authenticatedVoter" />
                </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<!-- use-expressions enables the @PreAuthorize -->
<http use-expressions="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
....
</http>
```

Note the beans added: they are three Spring components.

The first holds an unspecified reference. It expects something implementing [SecurityExpressionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionHandler.html): in your case you'll have to provide a [DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/method/DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.html)

Then, to add your custom token configuration, you'll need to write a filter of your own and wire it into the `HTTP` element. You can do it quite easily by extending Spring classes and then customizing its behaviour

```
public class MyClientAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    ....

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // custom logics here
        // throw exception for not authenticated
    }
}
```

and then wire it up

```
<bean class="x.y.z.MyClientAuthenticationFilter" id="myClientAuthenticationFilter" />
<http ....>
    <custom-filter ref="myClientAuthenticationFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</http>
```

You should be basically done.

Just remember to include `spring-security-aspects` in your build: Spring security `@PreAuthorize` and other annotations are intercepted via AOP, hence you'll need to provide these aspects in your classpath.

Also, keep in mind that this is not the full configuration: it would take a **very** long post to wire everything up: it is jut an example about how to start.

For deeper infos, rely on Spring Security documentation itself.

Last note: if you're using JvaConfig instead of XML, there should be annotations that can rid you of part of thi config, but the custom filter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Stefano for the hint. I setup the java config environment exactly based on your xml config and integrated the spring security features for my application. One more thing I did is that I added a filter in my application which adds an authentication in the SecurityContextHolder.getContext as I used token based authentication and for the next call the state is lost and I need to rebuild the state so that @PreAuthorize works fine.